# How do I prove that sum of reciprocals of first $2^n$ natural nos is always greater than $\frac{n+1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, summation-method

How can prove this inequality
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{r}\geq \frac{n+1}{2}
\end{equation}
Without using induction... Want to have an insight on summation inequalities

Comment: Do you mean $2^n$ or $2^r$ ?

Comment: I would advise against trying to prove it.

Comment: i meant  $2^r$ ...sorry

Comment: This isn't even true for n=1. Did you get the greater than and less than symbols mixed up?

Comment: But it's even less true (in a sense) for $n > 2$.  The left-hand side is always less than $1$ for positive finite $n$, and the right-hand side is always at least $1$ for positive finite $n$ (and steadily increasing, unlike the left-hand side).

Comment: I would avise against using the no-true-Scotsman theorem too.

Comment: Where did you see/hear of this inequality?  There must be some error in transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-negative integers $j$ we have,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^j} \frac{1}{2^j+k}\geq\sum_{k=1}^{2^j}\frac{1}{2^{j+1}}=\frac{2^j}{2^{j+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now, for $n\geq1$,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{r}=1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{2^j}\frac{1}{2^j+k}\right)\geq\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)=\frac{n+2}{2}$$

Equality holds for $n=1$.

This was the key observation of **Nicole Oresme** in his proof of divergence of the harmonic series $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}$$
Check this link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Oresme

Probably this post will help Denis James.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is this incorrect?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was not sure about the question at first and I don't know how to delete questions from this site

Comment: @DenisJames: in such cases, you can write it in the question or add a comment. I am removing my harsh comment. Don't forget to update the title.